# Ionic/Angular2 module causes error 'Cannot find module' but works as expected

Tags: angular, npm, import, ionic2

let's say we have default tabs ionic project.
we add dependency into package (npm i npmModuleName --save or npm i with edited package.json).
then we add import to page (component in reality) (import * as ModuleName from 'npmModuleName').
and here we face something strange: import line causes:

```
typescript error: cannot find module 'npmModuleName'.
```

but if closed - everything works just fine, i mean module npmModuleName is there and works perfectly.
so my question: how to fix/what to do?

extra info:
npmModuleName is js, not ts

```
index.js: module.exports = require('./src/npmModuleName');
./src/npmModuleName.js: module.exports = function (...) {...};
```

ionic info:
cordovaCLI: 7.0.1, ionicCLI: 2.2.2 (old, but cannot be upgraded right now), ionic framework: 2.3.0, applib: 2.2.1, appScripts: 1.2.0, node: 6

EDITED:
noticed, that if i run 'ionic serve' it fails during transpile with mentioned error and project is dead even if i close error.
when i do something (page.ts save) to trigger watcher - it rebuilds project and from that point on error still there but is closeable and project works just fine.

Comment: Do you have typescript installed?

Comment: yes, ionic project itself works, ionic project works even with imported module, but causes error.